# How to arrange numbers in four columns in C?

Tags: c

How to do this: 
I want to input two values (integers) and then show all numbers between these values in four columns.
For example:

```
    From 1 to 20:
    1 6  11 16
    2 7  12 17
    3 8  13 18
    4 9  14 19
    5 10 15 20
    -------------
    From 2 to 20:
    2 7  12 17
    3 8  13 18
    4 9  14 19
    5 10 15 20
    6 11 16
    -------------
    From 1 to 21:
    1 7  13 19
    2 8  14 20
    3 9  15 21
    4 10 16
    5 11 17
    6 12 18
```

Thanks

Comment: Try looking up `for` loop.

Comment: Hint: You can find the step-size between columns using `1 + (max - min)/4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void col4(int a, int b) {
    int rowsize = (b - a + 4) / 4;
    for (int row = 0; row < rowsize; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
            int n = a + row + col * rowsize;
            if (n <= b) {
                printf("%-2d ", n);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
    int a, b;
    if (2 != scanf("%d %d", &a, &b)) {
        return 1;
    }
    col4(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```